# Search and replace with lookarounds regex

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

Say I have multiple strings that contain ';'.  I want to get rid of ';'only if there is a comma contained in the string.  If there are no commas I want to leave the semi colon,';'.

An example of where I would like to get rid of the semi colon,';':

```
1,JoE,Stuff,more stuff; 05423089; 3029483-;98
```

Output:

```
1,JoE,Stuff,more stuff 05423089 3029483-98
```

I will be dealing with hundreds of thousands of rows of data.

Basically what I am doing here is where a file is delimited by commas, I want to omit all semi-colons,';'.  I know you can do this with regex look around but im not sure how to search and replace with them.

In the case that there is not a comma or it is not a comma delimited file, I would like to preserve all semi-colons.  I may have certain files that are delimited by a ';', or semi-colon.

Example:

1;JoE;Stuff;more stuff;054230893029483-98

In the above example, I do not want to remove the ';'.

Here is what I have so far:

```
s/((?=;)^.*?,.*?$)/$1/gi;
```

(?=;) checking for semi-colon encapsulated by (^.*?,.*?), which is the string I want to match.  I don't believe I am calling to my '$1' and '$2' correctly.

What is the proper way to search and replace with lookarounds..anyone?

Comment: How are you deciding that a comma is in a string?  Is this a fully CSV file, and so data commas are contained in double quotes?

Comment: @miller not always, I'am using the regex ^.*?,.*? to ensure that there are any commas in the file.  I could even go by if the file extension is a csv, remove ;.

Comment: My point is, you've listed a case where you want semicolons removed.  Care to also list the case where you want them preserved?

Comment: @miller did a re edit

Comment: What a simple solution all the while avoiding the regex lookaround.  Now I can use that same concept on multiple conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you basically want to remove all semicolons from a line if it contains a comma.

This is easily accomplished with the following perl one-liner

```
perl -i -pe 's/;//g if /,/' file.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-i[extension]`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `s/;//g`: Remove all semicolons from a line
- `if /,/`: Only if the line comtains a comma